# ../../src/corelib/global/qversiontagging.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

See here for Qt [official example](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/5.5/examples/widgets/desktop/systray)

I add CMakeLists.txt for it like so:

```
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qt5/qtbase)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
add_executable(systray main.cpp window.cpp)
target_link_libraries(systray Qt5::Widgets)
```

but I get this error upon running the systray executable:

```
/media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/qversiontagging.h:1:54: fatal error: ../../src/corelib/global/qversiontagging.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../../src/corelib/global/qversiontagging.h"
```

How can I make this example run?